# is it acceptable per code to paint over sub panel cover sticker?

Tags: electrical-panel

resurfaced basement wall, has a 14" x 14" sub panel mounted to it 50A or 60A.
This sub panel is 30+ years old, was in good condition, but the existing sticker on the face of it was not readable.  But the condition of the gray paint on the panel cover you can see its age and doesn't look great against a refinished wall.

Is there any reason that just the panel cover cannot be repainted, painting over the existing manufacturer sticker which is already not readable at all (at best you can only tell it was the manufacturer sticker) with rustoleum dark machine gray which is a very close color match?  Obviously if you say no you can't repaint then that implies whenever a panel sticker becomes unreadable the panel must be replaced?  Or can just a replacement cover be purchased?

Comment: We'd have to see the sticker.  If it says "thanks for buying Square D" then you're fine, but if it has critical panel data you're gonna want, or if it says "Thanks for buying Zinsco", we may have a different reco.  You can always just replace the panel should you ever need the label data. It's too small anyway.

Comment: Another option could be to use something like a vinyl wrap (like they use for cars).

Answer (score 1):

No problem painting over the front cover when door is closed and door of the panel. Don't paint the back side of the door or where the door covers the breakers.

Comment: for what reason to not paint the inside (or backside) of the door that covers the breakers?

Comment: @ron      There are usually circuit breaker labels there. If not, have at it.